# Why setting response header as dispatcher not working

Tags: java, aem

I am getting a weird behaviour that if I set the response header as

```
response.setHeader("dispatcher", "no-cache");
```

It is not working,but i change the text to any othe thing other than dispatcher it works...Any thoughts?

Here the response is not set to dispatcher...why?

Comment: What is not working? What error or behavior are you encountering?

Comment: @everybody see [this page](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/DispatcherNoCache.html) please.

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Adobe documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/DispatcherNoCache.html) referenced in several places:

> With the Dispatcher release 4.0.0 (and higher) a new header named "Dispatcher: no-cache" is introduced. This header informs the dispatcher not to cache the response. This header will then be removed by the dispatcher before forwarding the response to the client.

Adobe Dispatcher is a load balancer, which means it sits in front of several of your servers and processes incoming traffic.  When you set the header to:

```
response.setHeader("dispatcher", "no-cache");
```

then Dispatcher will *remove* the header and forward the response without caching.  So if by `"It is not working"` you mean your header is disappearing then this is the expected behavior.